# ESC PWM Duty Cycle between 20 - 70

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, pwm

I've wired my ESC and my Motor and I'm able to spin it at different speeds, but it only works between 20 - 70 DutyCycle.

How can I make it start spinning at 1 and max throttle at 100?

I'm using standard GPIO Python lib, this is my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wwRi.jpg

ESC: Cheetah HW30A Brushless ESC
Motor: I have no idea

Comment: Who can say?  ESCs normally work between 1ms (0% throttle) and 2ms (100% throttle).  How long are the pulses you are sending?  Some motors need a minimum power to spin, can't say I've heard of any stopping if the power is too high.

Comment: I've tried different frequencies and my code loops 0 - 100 duty cycle back and forth. Maybe there is actually a minimum power to spin and the ecu can cut power off if its too much? PS: I'm new in PWM if I say something stupid, don't laugh :D

Comment: ESCs use a specialised form of PWM.  They generally work like servos and respond to pulses happening at 50 Hz (times per second).  Each pulse should be between 1000µs and 2000µs.  This equates to a PWM dutycycle between 5%  and 10%.  A 5% dutycycle is 0 throttle, a 10% dutycycle is full throttle.  You need to check your maths to make sure you are sending pulses of the correct length.  Alternatively use (my) pigpio which sends reliable pulses.